# How to recover previous values in Mysql Table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter-table

I have MySQL Innodb table of 14M rows. There was a column called `is_disabled` which had different values. By mistake I ran the query without the where clause:

```
update url_queue set is_disabled=1
```

while wanted to run

```
update url_queue set is_disabled=1 where is_disabled=3;
```

I havent told my boss yet. And if somehow I can undo this before the meeting I would be able to save my job.

Please help!

Comment: Hopefully you have a backup - if you don't control the backups your gonna have to talk to someone that does sometime soon incase your backups over write themselves. I think you may be able to look at a log file for changes made - but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless you have a delayed replica, the only way to recover your old values is to restore the table from a backup.  sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Boss's never like to be kept in the dark.  Tell him/her right away, and work together on a recovery strategy.  Restore the most recent backup you have to another device, and start examining the table in question.  Good luck.